# addEventListener() to non-existent elements?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have attached a `click` event listener on an element like:

```
document.querySelector('.class-name').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    
});
```

The element may or may not get generated from the server-side.

So, if the server generates the element then all works fine but if not then I get an error like:

`Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`

I know why this happens, but I want to know whether there is a better way of attaching event listeners to elements that won't generate such errors?

Comment: `var el = document.querySelector('.class-name'); if (el) { el.addEventListener(...); }` ?

Comment: ... or event delegation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's no way of doing this without some sort of conditional test, but you can save a few characters compared to an `if` block thus:

```
var el = document.querySelector('.class-name');
el && el.addEventListener(...);
```

I don't believe there's any simple way of avoiding the temporary variable (but see below).

---

NB: the below is included just to show that it's possible and should not be construed as a recommendation ;-)

If this is a very common pattern in your HTML and JS, a way to avoid the temporary assignment to `el` is this:

```
var missing = {
  addEventListener: function() {};
};  // a "null" element

(document.querySelector('.className') || missing).addEventListener(...);
```

The idea being that the `|| missing` ensures that there's *something* present to absorb the `addEventListener` reference and invocation.

Comment: If you really want to avoid temp variable I would better just go with `try-catch`.

Comment: @dfsq yes, you could, albeit at the expense of longer code.  It's also arguable whether deliberately throwing an exception is this circumstance is "better".

Answer (score 10):

### Since ES2020

ES2020 introduced [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and that feature is exactly what you need here:

```
document.querySelector('.class-name')?.addEventListener('click', ()=> console.log("Clicked"));
```

Supported in all modern up-to-date browsers.

Answer (score 8):

Just check before if your element is here or not (like in comment ) :

```
var el = document.querySelector('.class-name');
if (el) { el.addEventListener(...); }
```

Edit : You can also wrap your element .class-name into a div and do something like that :

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
    var classes = e.target.className;
    if(classes = ".class-name")
        //DO SOMETHING
});
```

Comment: any other better way?

Comment: So you basically just copy-pasted my comment? :)

Comment: @dfsq any way he answerd.

Comment: I would write the same thing. And you can also wrap your .class-name into a div, add the event on the div, and check inside where you are.. i edit my post

Comment: No, problem. Since the answer is the same as I would answer it, I cannot not to upvote it, right? :)

Comment: Changing your DOM structure just to avoid a test in the code sounds like a really bad idea to me...

Comment: Yes, but it's an other way ^^

Answer (score 2):

You have to be sure that element exist. So

```
var element = document.querySelector('.class-name');

if (element)
   element.addEventListener('click', function () {});
```

Comment: I would just like to add, that, if the search for the DOM Element is done with something else then querySelector, check what it returns. For example, `getElementsByClassname` would always return an empty HTMLCollection. In that case a check again `element.length > 0` would be necessary.