# Any way to tell Flow that HTMLElement returned by getElementById() can't be null?

Tags: javascript, html, flowtype

My HTML contains all the elements I plan to hook into in my JS. I don't dynamically generate elements, so I can guarantee all my ID selectors will work. Yet the following code will generate an error in Flow that I can't check a property of a possibly null element:

```
document.getElementById('my-element').addEventListener(...);
```

The only workarounds I could figure out are:

```
((document.getElementById('my-element'): any): HTMLElement).addEventListener(...);
```

```
let element = document.getElementById('my-element');
if (element) {
    element.addEventListener(...);
}
```

Both methods hurt readability of the code and create more confusion in this case. Is there a cleaner approach to letting flow know that this element will not be null without beating around the bush?

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24825499/addeventlistener-to-non-existent-elements

Comment: @Casper that question is about this error in JavaScript (not Flow) because that author could NOT guarantee that his element will exist on the page at the time the code is executed. My case is the opposite and JavaScript always runs my version without errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the ID exists, you need to prove to Flow that it is found. That means you either need to check like your `if (element)` or `if (!element) throw new Error()`. That can be a pain to repeat in several places, so I would consider using  a helper function that requires it to not be null, e.g.

```
function getElementById(doc: Document, id: string): HTMLElement {
  const el = doc.getElementById(id);
  if (!el) throw new Error(`Unable to find element #${id}.`);
  return el;
}
```

then your code can safely do

```
getElementById(document, 'my-element').addEventListener(...);
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like the cleanest solution for now. Although I do wish there was something akin to TypeScript's `!` operator for cases like this.